# Count logical values in subset of columns using .SDcols argument to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` of logical values as follows:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
myDt <- data.table(id = paste0("id", 1:10))
myDt[, paste0(letters[1:3], sample(1:10, 9, replace = FALSE)) :=
       lapply(1:9, function(i) sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE))]
myDt
      id    a3    b4    c5    a7    b2    c8    a9    b6   c10
 1:  id1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 2:  id2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 3:  id3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 4:  id4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 5:  id5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 6:  id6 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 7:  id7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 8:  id8 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 9:  id9 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
10: id10  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The columns apart from `id` are three categories (`a`, `b` and `c`) each with 3 replicates (integer). I need to count the logical values for each category without knowing the replicate numbers in advance.

I can get the columns for category `a` as follows:

```
aCols <- grep("^a", names(myDt), value = TRUE)
myDt[, .SD, .SDcols = aCols, by = id]
      id    a3    a7    a9
 1:  id1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 2:  id2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 3:  id3  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 4:  id4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 5:  id5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 6:  id6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 7:  id7  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 8:  id8 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 9:  id9 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
10: id10  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

but then I'm stuck when trying to count the logical values. So far I've tried:

```
myDt[, sum(.SD), .SDcols = aCols, by = id]
Error in gsum(.SD) : 
  GForce sum can only be applied to columns, not .SD or similar. To sum all items in a list such as .SD, either add the prefix base::sum(.SD) or turn off GForce optimization using options(datatable.optimize=1). More likely, you may be looking for 'DT[,lappy(.SD,sum),by=,.SDcols=]'
```

and

```
myDt[, base::sum(.SD), .SDcols = aCols, by = id]
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

I did try the latter code with numerics instead of logicals and it gave me the expected result.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks for reading!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   plyr_1.8.3     tools_3.2.2    reshape2_1.4.1 Rcpp_0.12.0    stringi_0.5-5 
[7] stringr_1.0.0  chron_2.3-47
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have many columns of same type and you want to operate on them at once, it is usually better to tide up your data and the spread it again. Here's a possible solution using `melt` and `dcast` combination

```
# melt by the "id" column
res <- melt(myDt, id = "id") 
# Remove numeric values from column names
res[, indx := sub("\\d+", "", variable)] 
# Spread the data again according to the new index while counting `TRUE`s
dcast(res, id ~ indx, value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = function(x) sum(x == "TRUE"))
#       id a b c
#  1:  id1 2 0 3
#  2: id10 1 1 1
#  3:  id2 2 2 2
#  4:  id3 1 1 2
#  5:  id4 1 2 2
#  6:  id5 2 3 2
#  7:  id6 1 2 0
#  8:  id7 1 3 1
#  9:  id8 1 2 2
# 10:  id9 2 2 2
```

I've used the [development version here (v 1.9.5)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), you may need to use `dcast.data.table` instead of just `dcast` if you using v 1.9.4

---

Also, you mentioned you have *logical* values, but your example contained *character* values (`sample(c("TRUE", "FALSE"), 10, replace = TRUE))` instead of just `sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE))`), if your real data set truly have *logical* values, then the last step could be simplified to just

```
dcast(res, id ~ indx, value.var = "value", sum)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Example edited to make the values *truly* logical :)

Comment: Even though I added another answer below, this is the more elegant approach. In addition to elegance, it is *much* more general. For example, if the data were numeric rather than logical, one can change the `sum()` function when `dcast`ing to e.g. count values > 0 only, or some other needed criterion.

Answer (score 3):

I like @David Arenburg 's answer. Just to add another option -- use `rowSums()` instead of `sum()`. With your updated data, use

```
myDt[, a_cols := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = aCols]
myDt
          id    a3    b4    c5    a7    b2    c8    a9    b6   c10 a_cols
     1:  id1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      2
     2:  id2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      2
     3:  id3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      1
     4:  id4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      1
     5:  id5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      2
     6:  id6 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE      1
     7:  id7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE      1
     8:  id8 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      1
     9:  id9 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      2
    10: id10  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE      1
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I said I prefer your answer, it is more elegant and solves the actual problem. I added the `rowSums()` approach as an answer because it addresses the implicit question "Why doesn't `sum()` work in the op's use case?"

Comment: @Peter I agree with your comment about the other answer being better and more general. Although I was on the wrong track, I mentioned `.SDcols` and  `rowSums()` would have answered the question the way I asked it, so you get a vote too. Thanks!